# Formatting A Double In A String Without Scientific Notation

Tags: java, string, formatting, double, bigdecimal

I have a double. `double foo = 123456789.1234;`. I want to turn `foo` into a String. `String str = foo+"";`. But now `foo` is equal to "1.234567891234E8". Is there a way I can turn `foo` into a String without scientific notation?
I've tried

```
String str = String.format("%.0f", foo);
```

But that just removes the decimals. It sets `str` to "123456789";
I've tried

```
String str = (new BigDecimal(foo))+"";
```

But that loses accuracy. Its sets `str` to "123456789.1234000027179718017578125";

Comment: FYI, the `BigDecimal` approach does not lose accuracy -- it accurately describes the _actual_ value stored in that `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just `%f` instead of `%.0f`.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double foo = 123456789.1234;
        String str = String.format("%f", foo);
        System.out.println(str);

        // If you want to get rid of the trailing zeros
        str = new BigDecimal(str).stripTrailingZeros().toString();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123456789.123400
123456789.1234
```

Comment: For removing trailing zeros. Is using the Big Decimal a performance drop that I should be concerned about?

Comment: No...not that I am aware of...it has been there since Java-5 (and we have Java-15 today) and I have never heard/read about it causing any performance drop...however, you can always do benchmarking in case of any doubt.